# Libgdx getting Animation width and height with atlas

Tags: java, libgdx, height, width

I am starting with libgdx and I want to get the size of my animation. I have tried with:

```
width = atlas.findRegion("Idle_").getTexture().getWidth();
```

but it gives me "2048" that is the width of the spritesheet. I used the "gdx-texturepacker-3.2.0" to make all assets in one spritesheet with a .atlas file.

the .atlas file looks like this:

```
robotito.png
format: RGBA8888
filter: MipMap,MipMap
repeat: none
Idle_
  rotate: false
  xy: 1, 1117
  size: 567, 556
  orig: 567, 556
  offset: 0, 0
  index: 0
Idle_
  rotate: false
  xy: 1, 559
  size: 567, 556
  orig: 567, 556
  offset: 0, 0
  index: 1
```

I want to get that "size: 567, 556" sizes. Thank you for your help.

Comment: `width = atlas.findRegion("Idle_").getRegionWidth();`

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation on [`TextureRegion`](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/TextureRegion.html), these can probably help you:

> - public int getRegionHeight():
>     Returns the region's height.
> - public int getRegionWidth():
>     Returns the region's width.

Answer (score 0):

Your "idle_" is a 2 sprite atlas, so you have to decide if you want the with of the first one or how you do it.

TextureAtlas.AtlasRegion> tex = atlas.findRegion("Idle_");

To get the width of the FIRST sprite (index 0):
tex.get(0).width

if its packed you can get the packed value with:
tex.get(0).packedWidth